# Read but not write access to a socket on Linux, what can one do with that?

Tags: linux, permissions, socket

On a server installation, I found sockets writable by group, but only readable by others. I assume that the latter has no effect, as my understanding was that write access is needed to be able to work with those socket files. Is that correct?

Related: [Which systems do not honor socket read/write permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/which-systems-do-not-honor-socket-read-write-permissions)